# How to monitor unmounted/removed file systems of Linux in zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I want to configure a trigger that includes changes in number of the file-systems.

For example:

Assume, discovery found file-systems named 
 `c: and d: OR / and /disk1`.

If any of those discovered file-system removed, unmounted or added to the system.

So, I need to know how to create the trigger

Answer (score 0):

You can create an item that returns the current count drive (update every two hours).
Then create an item that also returns the current count drive, but update every 1 minute. 
After that - create a trigger than activated if the number in the first item doesn't equals in number in the second item.